# JS: Prevent Error if Accessing Attributes of Undefined Object

Tags: javascript

My goal: Test if the attribute of an object is/returns true. However, in some cases, the object is undefined.

---

This works no problem. The script continues normally.

`if(somethingUndefined){ }`

---

However, if I try to access an attribute of an undefined object, this generates an error and stops the script.

`if(somethingUndefined.anAttribute){ }`

---

Right now, this is what I'm using to solve the problem:

`if(somethingUndefined && somethingUndefined.anAttribute){ }`

---

Is there another way to do that? Maybe a global settings that will return false if the program tries to access an attribute of an undefined object?

Comment: `somethingUndefined && somethingUndefined.anAttribute` is a standard practice

Comment: I'd love it if we could check nested properties without getting fatal errors. Working with the WP API atm and my code looks like this all over the place; `if (this.post.featured_image && this.post.featured_image.media_details && this.post.featured_image.media_details.sizes && this.post.featured_image.media_details.sizes.large)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have many if statement like `if(somethingUndefined && somethingUndefined.anAttribute){ }`, then you could assign an empty object to it when it is undefined.

```
var somethingUndefined = somethingUndefined || {};

if (somethingUndefined.anAttribute) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of JavaScript's ability to assign variables within `if` conditions and follow this pattern for faster checks once you get past the first nested object.

<kbd>**[JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jsisnulltest)**</kbd>

```
var x; 
if(
   (x = somethingUndefined) && // somethingUndefined exists?
   (x = x.anAttribute) && // x and anAttribute exists?
   (x = x.subAttrubute) // x and subAttrubute exists?
){

}
```

vs the traditional

```
if(
    somethingUndefined && // somethingUndefined exists?
    somethingUndefined.anAttribute && // somethingUndefined and anAttribute exists?
    somethingUndefined.anAttribute.subAttribute // somethingUndefined and anAttribute and subAttribute exists?
){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it in your question is generally the way it's done in javascript. If you find yourself using this a lot, you could abstract it out into a function to make things a tiny bit cleaner for yourself, as such:

```
if (attrDefined(obj, 'property')) {
  console.log('it is defined, whoo!');
}

function attrDefined(o, p){ return !!(o && o[p]) }
```